# Mockito matchers, scala value class and NullPointerException

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

I'm using mockito with scalatest. I have following problem when using matcher with value class.

```java
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.BDDMockito._
import org.mockito.Matchers.any

case class FirstId(val value: String) extends AnyVal
case class SecondId(val value: String) extends AnyVal

trait MockedClass {
  def someMethods(firstId: FirstId, secondId: SecondId): Int
}

class ValueClassSpec() extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar {

  val mockedClass = mock[MockedClass]
  val secondId = SecondId("secondId")

  "Matchers" should "work for value class" in {
    // given
    given(mockedClass.someMethods(any[FirstId], org.mockito.Matchers.eq(secondId))).willReturn(3)
    // when
    val result = mockedClass.someMethods(FirstId("firstId"), secondId)
    // then
    assert(result == 3)
  }

}
```

and the result is:

```java
ValueClassSpec:
Matchers
- should work for value class *** FAILED ***
  java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at io.scalac.fow.party.ValueClassSpec$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ValueClassSpec.scala:22)
  at io.scalac.fow.party.ValueClassSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(ValueClassSpec.scala:20)
  at io.scalac.fow.party.ValueClassSpec$$anonfun$1.apply(ValueClassSpec.scala:20)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
  at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
  at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1639)
  ...
```

I found similar question ([Scala Value classes and Mockito Matchers don't play together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974493/scala-value-classes-and-mockito-matchers-dont-play-together)) but without any advice.

Is there any posibility to use mockito matchers with scala value class?

Lib versions: scala 2.11.2, mockito 1.10.8, scalatest 2.1.6

Comment: afaik `any` and `eq` cannot be used together.

Comment: @Ashalynd - from [Mockito documentation](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html): **Warning on argument matchers:**

If you are using argument matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.

E.g: (example shows verification but the same applies to stubbing):

    verify(mock).someMethod(anyInt(), anyString(), eq("third argument"));
    //above is correct - eq() is also an argument matcher

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The proper solution is:

```scala
case class StringValue(val text: String) extends AnyVal
case class LongValue(val value: Long) extends AnyVal

val eqFirst: StringValue = StringValue(org.mockito.Matchers.eq("first"))
val anySecond: StringValue = StringValue(org.mockito.Matchers.any[String])

val eqFirst: LongValue = LongValue(org.mockito.Matchers.eq(1L))
val anySecond: LongValue = LongValue(org.mockito.Matchers.any[Long])
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a bunch of warnings and errors about not using matchers outside of stubbing:

val anyProjectName = org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any[String].asInstanceOf[ProjectName]

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

Comment: I validate that `MyAnyValClass(any[String])` works without NPE in Scala 2.12.7 and Mockito 2.28

Answer (score 11):

I found solution:

```
val anyFirstId: FirstId = any[String].asInstanceOf[FirstId]
val eqSecondId: SecondId = org.mockito.Matchers.eq[String](secondId.value).asInstanceOf[SecondId]
given(mockedClass.someMethods(anyFirstId, eqSecondId)).willReturn(3)
```

Comment: It would be cool if you implement your own matcher for AnyVals and put it on GitHub.

Comment: It's not easy to write generic eq matcher for AnyVal.

Comment: Has this worked for you? I get a ClassCastException.

Comment: Ah, I see, it seems to work for String value classes but not for any primitive value classes: http://pastebin.com/pUF3muEF

Comment: @cristian-vrabie So what is solution for value classes with primitives such as Int?

Comment: Thanks for that useful answer. Could you explain _why_ this works, unlike the "traditional" way ?

Comment: I validate that `any[String].asInstanceOf[FirstId]` works in Scala 2.12.7 and Mockito 2.28.

Answer (score 5):

This works for all kinds of `extends AnyVal` value classes and doesn't need special matchers either:

```
    given(mockedClass.someMethods(FirstId(anyString), SecondId(org.mockito.Matchers.eq(secondId.value)))).willReturn(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

The newest version of `mockito-scala` (0.0.9) supports this out of the box, you can do something like

```
when(myObj.myMethod(anyVal[MyValueClass]) thenReturn "something"

myObj.myMethod(MyValueClass(456)) shouldBe "something"

verify(myObj).myMethod(eqToVal[MyValueClass](456))
```

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of that library

Comment: Hi, is mockito-scala an active project? Apologies for upfront, I am asking as I don't know if it would be risky switching from mockito to mockito-scala

Comment: Yes it is, look at the commit and release history https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala

Comment: Interestingly, the `any[MyValueClass]` method fails when the value class has a private constructor, other than that, the `eqTo` works as expected, thanks!

Comment: @AlexITC what scala version are you on?

Comment: The version is 2.12.2.

Comment: Yes, that's because the current macro does something like `new MyValueClass(any)`, I just improved it to check if it is also a `case class` first and in that case use the `apply` method. The next release should have it, keep tuned!

Answer (score 1):

If you have shapeless in your dependencies you could consider my little helper method: https://gist.github.com/Fristi/bbc9d0e04557278f8d19976188a0b733

Instead of writing

`UserId(is(context.userId.value))`

You can write

`isAnyVal(context.userId)`

Which is a bit more convenient :-)

Answer (score 0):

My class also extended AnyVal

```scala
case class ApplicationKey(value: String) extends AnyVal {
  override def toString: String = value
}
```

and this worked for me:

```scala
   when(waterfallLogicEventWriter.writeAuctionEvents(            
     Eq(waterfallRequest.auctionId), Eq(waterfallRequest.ip),
     ApplicationKey(any[String]),                                
     any()).thenReturn(waterfallEvents)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there's anyone looking for a macro-based solution that works with `AnyVal` classes with *private* constructors, here's something that worked for me: https://gist.github.com/lloydmeta/e4ba5af6dae8f1c68efc6458f0a5879d

I tried doing this the "normal" way without macros, but I suspect there may be byte-code manipulation-related things happening that break normal assumptions around function substitution.