# Mockito - NullpointerException when stubbing Method

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, stubbing

So I started writing tests for our Java-Spring-project.

What I use is JUnit and Mockito. It's said, that when I use the when()...thenReturn() option I can mock services, without simulating them or so. So what I want to do is, to set:

```
when(classIwantToTest.object.get().methodWhichReturnsAList(input))thenReturn(ListcreatedInsideTheTestClass)
```

But no matter which when-clause I do, I always get a NullpointerException, which of course makes sense, because input is null.

Also when I try to mock another method from an object:

```
when(object.method()).thenReturn(true)
```

There I also get a Nullpointer, because the method needs a variable, which isn't set.

But I want to use when()..thenReturn() to get around creating this variable and so on. I just want to make sure, that if any class calls this method, then no matter what, just return true or the list above.

Is it a basically misunderstanding from my side, or is there something else wrong?

**Code:**

```
public class classIWantToTest implements classIWantToTestFacade{
        @Autowired
        private SomeService myService;

        @Override
        public Optional<OutputData> getInformations(final InputData inputData) {
            final Optional<OutputData> data = myService.getListWithData(inputData);
            if (data.isPresent()) {
                final List<ItemData> allData = data.get().getItemDatas();
                    //do something with the data and allData
                return data;
            }

            return Optional.absent();
        }   
}
```

And here is my test class:

```
public class Test {

    private InputData inputdata;

    private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    final List<ItemData> allData = new ArrayList<ItemData>();

    @Mock
    private DeliveryItemData item1;

    @Mock
    private DeliveryItemData item2;



    @Mock
    private SomeService myService;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
        myService = mock(myService.class); 
        classUnderTest.setService(myService);
        item1 = mock(DeliveryItemData.class);
        item2 = mock(DeliveryItemData.class);

    }


    @Test
    public void test_sort() {
        createData();
        when(myService.getListWithData(inputdata).get().getItemDatas());

        when(item1.hasSomething()).thenReturn(true);
        when(item2.hasSomething()).thenReturn(false);

    }

    public void createData() {
        item1.setSomeValue("val");
        item2.setSomeOtherValue("test");

        item2.setSomeValue("val");
        item2.setSomeOtherValue("value");

        allData.add(item1);
        allData.add(item2);


}
```

Comment: the object in when() must be a mock created by Mockito.mock(), it does not work for manually created real objects - not sure if that's your issue, since I'm not really getting where your problem is...

Comment: It sounds like `classIwantToTest.object.get()` result is not a mock, or that `get()` is returning null. But please post your code, showing your test, and initialization of your mocks.

Comment: Added some code. Needed to change the variable-names, since it's from my company ;).

Comment: Help for visitors to this question: Make sure you haven't accidentally got `final` in your method signature. That's another hard to track down route cause of an NPE here

Comment: please create a minimal example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The default return value of methods you haven't stubbed yet is `false` for boolean methods, an empty collection or map for methods returning collections or maps and `null` otherwise.

This also applies to method calls within `when(...)`. In you're example `when(myService.getListWithData(inputData).get())` will cause a NullPointerException because `myService.getListWithData(inputData)` is `null` - it has not been stubbed before.

One option is create mocks for all intermediate return values and stub them before use. For example:

```
ListWithData listWithData = mock(ListWithData.class);
when(listWithData.get()).thenReturn(item1);
when(myService.getListWithData()).thenReturn(listWithData);
```

Or alternatively, you can specify a different default answer when creating a mock, to make methods return a new mock instead of null: `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`

```
SomeService myService = mock(SomeService.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(myService.getListWithData().get()).thenReturn(item1);
```

You should read the Javadoc of [Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/Answers.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) which explains this in more detail and also has some warnings about its usage.

I hope this helps. Just note that your example code seems to have more issues, such as missing assert or verify statements and calling setters on mocks (which does not have any effect).

Comment: Where can I find the specification/docs for the first sentence of the answer? Thanks!

Comment: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.20.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEFAULTS or have a look at the source: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/v2.20.0/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/defaultanswers/ReturnsEmptyValues.java#L20-L49

Comment: for me changing `when().thenReturn()` to `doReturn().when()` clause fixed the issue. Also Junit5 and mockito use `any()` instead `anyString()`

Answer (score 368):

I had this issue and my problem was that I was calling my method with `any()` instead of `anyInt()`.  So I had:

```
doAnswer(...).with(myMockObject).thisFuncTakesAnInt(any())
```

and I had to change it to:

```
doAnswer(...).with(myMockObject).thisFuncTakesAnInt(anyInt())
```

I have no idea why that produced a NullPointerException.  Maybe this will help the next poor soul.

Comment: This worked for me. Leaving this comment for the next poor soul.

Comment: Matchers wont work for primitives, so if the argument is a primitive you will will need the anyChar/Int/Boolean etc.

Comment: not allowing `any()` to work for all variables and having it manifest itself as a NPE is tantamount to a cyber warfare attack on dev teams.

Comment: The reason why is that any() returns a generic object reference.  This object is unboxed to an integer, so the generic type is determined to be 'Integer'. The object is null though, so the unboxing fails accessing a null pointer.  anyInt() provides a native integer, so it works.

Comment: changing any() to anyInt() solved it for me too - thanks! (my case involved java tests and kotlin classes)

Comment: Id suggest anyone reading this to try out this solution before going for the accepted answer.

Comment: this answer should be at least close after the accepted answer, all ordered by answer upvotes

Comment: I have this issue with a value class wrapping String

Comment: "This worked for me. Leaving this comment for the next poor soul."
...... 5 years passed......
I'm the next poor soul lol.

Comment: Thank you this is indeed the solution. I initially had `anyInt()` and `anyLong()` along with `anyString()` but then my mock was not being invoked because one of the strings was `null`! So I moved them all to `any()` just to be safe, but then it started throwing NPE.

Comment: @BingRen ...and still we come.

Comment: Works for boolean as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 87):

I had the same problem and my issue was simply that I had not annotated the class properly using @RunWith. In your example, make sure that you have:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
...
```

Once I did that, the NullPointerExceptions disappeared.

Comment: I got null pointer bcoz of 
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class),  instead of that I changed to @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class).

Comment: For Kotlin : @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)

Comment: Having the same problem using Junit 5 , I resolve it using : @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) instead of @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
.

Answer (score 34):

For future readers, another cause for NPE when using mocks is forgetting to initialize the mocks like so:

```
@Mock
SomeMock someMock;

@InjectMocks
SomeService someService;

@Before
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); //without this you will get NPE
}

@Test
public void someTest(){
    Mockito.when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn("some result");
   // ...
}
```

Also make sure you are using JUnit for all annotations.
I once accidently created a test with @Test from testNG so the @Before didn't work with it (in testNG the annotation is @BeforeTest)

Comment: @BeforeEach helped me here but it always depends on execution context.

Comment: +1 for the "make sure your are using JUnit for all annotations"! Somehow, Intellij assumed I want to use `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `import org.junit.Test` which caused the mocks to be null apparently.

Comment: I somehow missed this line "MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); "

Comment: In my case i forgot to initialize my variables effectively THANK YOU !!

Answer (score 30):

For me the reason I was getting NPE is that I was using `Mockito.any()` when mocking primitives. I found that by switching to using the correct variant from mockito gets rid of the errors.

For example, to mock a function that takes a primitive `long` as parameter, instead of using `any()`, you should be more specific and replace that with `any(Long.class)` or `Mockito.anyLong()`.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I was getting errors that made no sense but using Mockito.anyInt() rather than Mockito.any() solved it. 

Example Error: `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected... You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.`

Comment: Thanks !!! I used anyString() and anyBoolean() instead of any() and test passed . Thank you so much .

Answer (score 20):

As this is the closest I found to the issue I had, it's the first result that comes up and I didn't find an appropriate answer, I'll post the solution here for any future poor souls:

`any()` doesn't work where mocked class method uses a primitive parameter.

```
 public Boolean getResult(String identifier, boolean switch)
```

The above will produce the same exact issue as OP.

Solution, just wrap it:

```
 public Boolean getResult(String identifier, Boolean switch)
```

The latter solves the NPE.

- *keep in mind if you choose this approach, now you might want to include a nullcheck for Boolean in production code* (credit: brought up by Ridcully)

Comment: That was exactly what happened to me.

Comment: For the find and the solution

Comment: So to fix an error/bug in a test, you have to change production code? I don't think that's the correct approach. Actually, you just allow null as a value for switch, so you' d now have to implement all the cases where switch is null as well, in your method.

Comment: That's a good remark, Ridcully. I'll add that note. Thanks

Comment: Or better you can replace any() with anyBoolean() and keep the primitive in your code...

Comment: That is better, upvoted :)

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you initialize your mocks.

`JUnit4` use `@Before`

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

`JUnit5` use `@BeforeEach`

```
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

For `JUnit5` check, you are using proper imports also.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Comment: initMocks is deprecated, use MockitoAnnotations.openMocks instead

Comment: I am using JUnit version 4 and i still needed "@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)" annotation for "when" method to work properly.

Comment: The last note about jUnit5 is wrong since it actually regards jUnit4. Compare answers of @PoulamiPal https://stackoverflow.com/a/67142144/4240261 and of noobie2023 https://stackoverflow.com/a/73337513/4240261

Answer (score 8):

**Corner case:**
If you're using **Scala** and you try to create an `any` matcher on a **value class**, you'll get an unhelpful NPE.

So given `case class ValueClass(value: Int) extends AnyVal`, what you want to do is `ValueClass(anyInt)` instead of `any[ValueClass]`

```
when(mock.someMethod(ValueClass(anyInt))).thenAnswer {
   ...
   val v  = ValueClass(invocation.getArguments()(0).asInstanceOf[Int])
   ...
}
```

This other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289757/mockito-matchers-scala-value-class-and-nullpointerexception) is more specifically about that, but you'd miss it when you don't know the issue is with value classes.

Answer (score 7):

For JUnit 5 the test class has to be annotated with:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

imports:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
```

My issue was fixed with this addition.

Answer (score 6):

you need to initialize MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this) method has to called to initialize annotated fields.

```
   @Before public void initMocks() {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }
```

for more details see [Doc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)

Comment: Using `org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach` insted of `@Before` helped me.

Answer (score 5):

Check that the method signature **is not declared as** `final`

This one catches out a lot of people who work on codebases which are subjected to Checkstyle and have internalised the need to mark members as `final`.

i.e. in the OP's example:

`object.method()`

Make sure that `method()` is not declared as `final`:

```
public final Object method() {
}
```

Mockito cannot mock a final method and this will come up as a wrapped NPE:

```
Suppressed: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
```

Buried deep in the error message is the following:

```
Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

Comment: This was my problem. If you don't control the source you're mocking, you can get around it using [an extension](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, my Mockito annotation didn't match the JUnit Version.

1. When using `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` make sure you're using JUnit 5: `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`
2. When using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` make sure you're using JUnit 4: `import org.junit.Test;`

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers helped me. I was struggling to understand why code works in Java but **not** in Kotlin.

Then I figured it out from [this thread](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/255#issuecomment-395099869).

You have to make class and member functions `open`, otherwise NPE was being thrown.

After making function `open` tests started to pass.

You might as well consider using compiler's ["all-open" plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html):

> Kotlin has classes and their members ***final by default***, which makes it inconvenient to use frameworks and libraries such as Spring AOP that require classes to be **open**. The `all-open` compiler plugin adapts Kotlin to the requirements of those frameworks and **makes classes annotated with a specific annotation and their members open** without the explicit open keyword.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was because I was stubbing the mock in the `@BeforeAll` method.

`MockitoExtension` does not have a callback for `@BeforeAll`.

```
public class MockitoExtension implements BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback, ParameterResolver
```

I moved the stubbing inside the test method it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was the wrong import for `when()`.

I used `import static reactor.core.publisher.Mono.when` by accident.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, Intellij created Test with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` (Junit5) instead of import `org.junit.Test` of (Junit4) which caused all beans to be null apparently.
also, make sure the class and test method is public

Answer (score 1):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) //(OR) PowerMockRunner.class

@PrepareForTest({UpdateUtil.class,Log.class,SharedPreferences.class,SharedPreferences.Editor.class})
public class InstallationTest extends TestCase{

@Mock
Context mockContext;
@Mock
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
@Mock
SharedPreferences.Editor mSharedPreferenceEdtor;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
//        mockContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
//        mSharedPreferences = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.class);
//        mSharedPreferenceEdtor = Mockito.mock(SharedPreferences.Editor.class);
    when(mockContext.getSharedPreferences(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(mSharedPreferences);
    when(mSharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(mSharedPreferenceEdtor);
    when(mSharedPreferenceEdtor.remove(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mSharedPreferenceEdtor);
    when(mSharedPreferenceEdtor.putString(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mSharedPreferenceEdtor);
}

@Test
public void deletePreferencesTest() throws Exception {

 }
}
```

All the above commented codes are not required 
{ `mockContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);` },
if you use **@Mock** Annotation to `Context mockContext;`

```
@Mock 
Context mockContext;
```

But it will work if you use **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)** only. As per Mockito you can create mock object by either using *@Mock or Mockito.mock(Context.class);* ,

I got NullpointerException because of using @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class), instead of that I changed to @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) it works fine

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I missed add first

```
PowerMockito.spy(ClassWhichNeedToBeStaticMocked.class);
```

so this can be helpful to somebody who see such error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.addAnswersForStubbing(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:67)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:42)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.PowerMockitoStubberImpl.when(PowerMockitoStubberImpl.java:112)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case it was because of wrong annotation usage. I was using junit 4 for testing and used `@BeforeEach` instead of `@Before` while initializing.

Changed it to `@Before` and it works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

This is where google took me when I had the same `NullPointerException` with Junit 5, but was correctly using `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` in my maven project.

Turns out I hadn't included the `maven-surefire-plugin` in my pom.xml and that meant the `@ExtendWith` wasn't actually doing anything!

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using wrong annotation/import of Mock, so my object was not getting formed.
I was using `org.evosuite.shaded.org.mockito.Mock` and I switched back to `org.mockito.Mock`. Then as if by magic, it started working for me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Fix Static Import

Please check the static import. It seems like this is the issue.

**The correct import should be:**

`import static org.mockito.Mockito.when`

**Instead of:**

`import static reactor.core.publisher.Mono.when`.

Comment: This one worked for me and I knew I didn't pay attention as to what I was importing when I started to write the "when" statement. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Ed Webb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169554/2073130) helped in my case. And instead, you can also try add

```
  @Rule public Mocks mocks = new Mocks(this);
```

if you `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. This answer doesn't solve OP's issue but since this post is the only one that shows up on googling this issue, I'm sharing my answer here.

I came across this issue while writing unit tests for Android. The issue was that the activity that I was testing extended `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`. To fix this, I was able to just replace `AppCompatActivity` with `Activity` since I didn't really need it. This might not be a viable solution for everyone, but hopefully knowing the root cause will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

When using JUnit 5 or above. You have to inject the class annotated with `@Mock`
in an `@BeforeEach` setup.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to wrong import of the @Test annotation

Make sure you are using the following import

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the test class with: `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a tested method called another method as a parameter:

```
Mockito.`when`(repository.getItems(prefs.getUser().id)).thenReturn(listOf())`
```

While `repository` is mocked, `prefs.getUser().id)` will throw NPE. So, first we should mock a parameter, for instance,

```
Mockito.`when`(prefs.getUser()).thenReturn(User(id = 1, name = "user"))`
```

Also we should mock `prefs`. I didn't check it and changed a library, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to mock a "final" method, which apparently was the problem.

The right way to handle this would be to use an interface and mock that interface however I couldn't control the library where the "final" method was.

Mockito 2 can handle mocking final method. Add a text file to the project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and add a single line of text:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

After that, mocking the final method should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of Junit you are using. In the Maven/Gradle build tool, if you set to use `testRuntimeOnly 'junit5'`,then it might not take `@RunWith` since it is not available and it is replaced with `@ExtendWith` in Junit5.

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt answer the OP's original query, but its here to try help others with Mockito null pointer exceptions (NPE).

My NPE was happening as I did not explicitly set the class under tests' dependencies to be the classes I had mocked. So the class under test was unable to find its required dependencies, creating the NPE. I tend to not mock the class under test (i.e. use `new` keyword), to ensure im getting my native class behaviour for testing.

Im still using Junit 4 for reasons outside my control. Worked example;

**ClassUnderTest**

```java
public class ClassUnderTest {
    private DependantClassOne dependantClassOne; 
    private DependantClassTwo dependantClassTwo;

    // remaining class, including setters
}
```

**Test Class**

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Test {
    private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;
    private DependantClassOne dependantClassOne;
    private DependantClassTwo dependantClassTwo;
 
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        dependantClassOne = mock(DependantClassOne.class);
        dependantClassTwo = mock(DependantClassTwo.class);
        classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();

        classUnderTest.setDependantClassOne(dependantClassOne); //added to prevent NPE
        classUnderTest.setDependantClassTwo(dependantClassTwo); //added to prevent NPE
    }

    // tests
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case UnderTest class has two kind of injections: via constructor(TheSecondService) and via setters(TheFirstService).

All injections via setters was null. This helps:

```
@Mock
private TheFirstService theFirstService;
@Mock
private TheSecondService theSecondService;
@InjectMocks
private TheThirdService underTest;
  
@BeforeEach
public void setup() {
    underTest.setTheFirstService(theFirstService);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case i was missing the annotation `@mock` in the mapper declaration.

Comment: Hi Ives. Did you want to comment sharing your experience? Kindly use the relevant section for that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).