# NPE when mocking Annotation method

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, mockito, testng

The task is to cause `NoSuchMethodException` exception when calling `table.annotationType().getMethod("name")`.

I have following code

```
@Mock(answer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private Table table;

@Test(expectedExceptions = NoSuchMethodException.class)
public void testGetSupportClassesDatabaseThrowException() throws NoSuchMethodException {
    String testPackageName = "com.usc.dbd.util.supporttable";

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(table.annotationType().getMethod("name")).thenThrow(NoSuchMethodException.class);

    SupportTables.getSupportClasses(testPackageName);
}
```

The test fails with `NullPointerException` on `when...` line.

```
testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.17")
```

`Table` is annotation from `javax.persistence`

Probably the issue is in mocking `Table` interface.

I'm looking for solution how to test such case.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to share you complete set of dependencies? I would like to try and figure out what is causing the `NullPointerException` but I havent been able to narrow down on the dependencies properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito - NullpointerException when stubbing Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124153/mockito-nullpointerexception-when-stubbing-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things here:

- the NPE is strange ( will see if I can find an explanation later on )
- even without an NPE, your test is pointless

You see, you create **one** mocked instance of the Table class. That you configure to react to a certain call with an exception.

Then you call a *static* method, without using that mocked object in any way. That simply will not do anything.

That later, static call doesn't know **anything** about your mocked table instance. You probably assume that your mock setup will affect *any* Table object. No, it will not! It only affects calls that happen on that *specific* object.

If you want to control *any arbitrary* instance of Table, created anywhere, you have way more things to do (for example you would have to look into using PowerMock or JMockit to intercept/control constructor calls).

Long story short: as written right now, your test case doesn't at all do what you wrote it for.

Comment: Starting with a question, this seems to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: mockito version 2.7.17; 
`Table` is annotation from `javax.persistence`; 
`annotationType()` is method from `java.lang.annotation`.

Comment: @Turing85 Not necessarily. And if that helps: with more information from the OP, I could rewrite it without a question mark. Well, still a question mark regarding the NPE ...

Comment: @AStefanovskiy See my updates. In short: I think your whole test is bogus. Even without that NPE, it wouldnt do what you think it should do.