# Mockito NoSuchElementException when() findById() get() thenReturn()

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5, mockitowhen

Trying to test my service with Mockito library, and I bumped into a problem, please see below the error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
at org.HappyRestApi.springREST.services.BankDepositServiceTests.findBankDepositById(BankDepositServiceTests.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I have tried to solve this issue with using a similar article on stack there is the link:
[Mockito - NullpointerException when stubbing Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33124153/mockito-nullpointerexception-when-stubbing-method)

Please see my code which is involved

Repository:

```
import org.HappyRestApi.springREST.domain.BankDeposit;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BankDepositRepositorie extends JpaRepository<BankDeposit,Long> {
}
```

service:

```
package org.HappyRestApi.springREST.services;

import org.HappyRestApi.springREST.domain.BankDeposit;
import org.HappyRestApi.springREST.repositories.BankDepositRepositorie;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BankDepositServiceImpl implements BankDepositService {

    private final BankDepositRepositorie bankDepositRepositorie;

    public BankDepositServiceImpl(BankDepositRepositorie bankDepositRepositorie) {
        this.bankDepositRepositorie = bankDepositRepositorie;
    }

    @Override
    public BankDeposit findBankDepositById(Long id) {
        return bankDepositRepositorie.findById(id).get();
    }

    @Override
    public List<BankDeposit> findAllBankDeposit() {
        return bankDepositRepositorie.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addBankDeposit(BankDeposit bankDeposit) {
        this.bankDepositRepositorie.save(bankDeposit);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteBankDepositaById(Long id){
        this.bankDepositRepositorie.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
package org.HappyRestApi.springREST.services;

import org.HappyRestApi.springREST.domain.BankDeposit;
import org.HappyRestApi.springREST.domain.enums.Period;
import org.HappyRestApi.springREST.repositories.BankDepositRepositorie;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Date;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BankDepositServiceTests {

    private BankDepositServiceImpl bankDepositService;
    private BankDeposit b1;

    @Mock
    BankDepositRepositorie bankDepositRepositorie;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() throws Exception{
        bankDepositService = new BankDepositServiceImpl(bankDepositRepositorie);

        b1 = new BankDeposit();
        b1.setId(1L);
        b1.setName("jakaslokata1");
        b1.setInterest(0.1);
        b1.setCapitalizationPeriod(Period.TWELVE_MONTHS);
        b1.setPeriodOfValidityStart(new Date());
        b1.setPeriodOfValidityEnd(new Date());
    }

    @Test
    public void findBankDepositById() throws Exception {

        when(bankDepositRepositorie.findById(anyLong()).get()).thenReturn(b1);

        BankDeposit result = bankDepositService.findBankDepositById(1L);

        Assert.assertNotNull(b1);
        Assert.assertEquals("jakaslokata1", b1.getName());

    }
}
```

It seems that the issue is related to this line of code in test class:

```
when(bankDepositRepositorie.findById(anyLong()).get()).thenReturn(b1);

But i'm not really sure, does anyone have any suggestions?
```

Comment: `Optional.get` throws an exception when the `Optional` is empty. Use `...(anyLong()).orElse(null)...` instead.

Comment: Your solution allowed me to one line further, ant now this line gives me java.lang.NullPointerException:
BankDeposit result = bankDepositService.findBankDepositById(1L);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [findById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts) returns an Optional, so you could try:

```
when(bankDepositRepositorie.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(b1));
```

It seems that the init() method is not being run, as @LukeWoodward mentioned you have a mismatch between Junit4 and Junit5. Replace `@BeforeEach` with `@Before`.

Comment: This solution gives me the java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Szelek Where does it gives you NullPointerException?

Comment: @Daniem, in the line when(bankDepositRepositorie.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(b1));

Comment: @Szelek Could you debug the test and see which variable is null? Please check b1 is not null

Comment: @Szelek It seems the init() method is not being run

Comment: Yes your right, I have moved the initializing the b1 instance to my test method. But now I am still receiving the NPE. in this line "BankDeposit result = bankDepositService.findBankDepositById(1L);", even if the object b1 is not Null.

Comment: @Szelek Check if bankDepositService is null

Comment: @Szelek: `init()` isn't being called because your test class contains a mish-mash of JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 annotations.  Try replacing `@BeforeEach` with `@Before`.

Comment: @Szelek try the suggestion of LukeWoodward

Comment: @Szelek Updated the answer, see if it solves your issue now