# In the unit test of TestNG, nullPointerException is always reported when using the mokito stub function, I did not find a solution

Tags: java, mockito, testng

This is a springmvc project based on gradle, I'm unit testing it using TestNG. When I mock a service layer class and stub its methods, "`when (). ThenReturn ()`" keeps reporting NullPointerException, I tried Many solutions on this site are not suitable for my situation.

controller:

```
package app.dnatask.controller;

import ...

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/API/scanresultconfigure")

public class ScanResultConfigureController extends BaseController {
    @Autowired
    private ScanResultConfigureService scanResultConfigureService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/queryScanResultList/{taskId}/{externalname}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public IBaseResult queryscanResultList(final HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable final String taskId, @PathVariable final String externalname, @RequestBody Map map) throws Exception {
        return runController(new IControllRunner() {
            public void run(IOutResult or, CheckResult cr) throws Exception {
                List<ScanResultTitleConfigurePO> list = scanResultConfigureService.findtitleConfigure(taskId, externalname, map);
                ......
            }
        }
    }
}
```

service:

```
package app.dnatask.service;

import ...

@Slf4j
@Service
public class ScanResultConfigureService {
    @Autowired
    private Demo1 demo1;
    @Autowired
    private Demo2 demo2;
    @Autowired
    private Demo3 demo3;

    public List<ScanResultTitleConfigurePO> findtitleConfigure(String taskId, String externalname, Map m) {
        //Query database
        List<ScanResultTitleConfigurePO> list = scanResultTitleConfigureRepository.findByTaskId(taskId, externalname);
        ......
        retuen list;
    }
}
```

unit test:

```
package app.dnatask.controller;

import ...

@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ScanResultConfigureController.class})
@ComponentScan(
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = {
                        ComponentScan.class, Configuration.class, ImportResource.class
                })
        },
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        lazyInit = true
)
@EnableWebMvc
public class ScanResultConfigureControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @MockBean(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private ScanResultConfigureService scanResultConfigureService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).dispatchOptions(true).build();
        Demo1 demo1 = mock(Demo1.class,Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        Demo2 demo2 = mock(Demo2.class,Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        Demo3 demo3 = mock(Demo3.class,Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    }

     @Test
    public void testQueryscanResultList() throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        testMap.put("key1", "value1");
        testMap.put("key2", "value2");
        String requestJson = JSONObject.toJSONString(testMap);
        List testList = new ArrayList();
        testList.add("test1");
        testList.add("test2");

        when(scanResultConfigureService.findtitleConfigure(anyString(), anyString(), anyMap())).thenReturn(testList);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(
                post("/API/scanresultconfigure/queryScanResultList/{taskId}/{externalname}", "123", "abc")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(requestJson)
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

Exception message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.dnatask.controller.ScanResultConfigureControllerTest.testQueryscanResultList(ScanResultConfigureControllerTest.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:239)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:180)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:251)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:139)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:155)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:137)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This problem has bothered me for many days ... I really need your help ..

Comment: I have tried ```@MockBean (answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS) ```or ```@MockBean``` and still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: The error location is in the unit test: ```when(scanResultConfigureService.findtitleConfigure(anyString(), anyString(), anyMap())).thenReturn(testList);```

Comment: See this example for more clarity on my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33215620/4964136

Comment: I want to ask a question: The unit test of the controller is just a test using mockmvc, right?

Comment: Yes, It is just an extension.

Comment: Sorry, i still have some questions.My service layer has three database layer injections. Is this Demo1 ~ 3 the intermediate data? But why do I still stub NullPointerException in the unit test?

Comment: I have re-edited the service code described in the problem. Could you please check it?

Comment: Try changing `@Autowired` to `@Component`

Comment: Thank you for your mention, that is to say, if I create a new po, I will first mock this po, right?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at the basic difference: http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2014/03/using-component-and-autowired-annotations-spring.html

Comment: Ok thank you, i will try to modify my code to make it work

Comment: It's frustrating, I still can't solve my problem.In ```scanResultConfigureService.findtitleConfigure```, I added, deleted, and checked the data in the database. I do n’t know how to handle this situation, and I do n’t know how to mock this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an annotation above the class of the unit test will solve the problem:

`@TestExecutionListeners (listeners = MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `NullpointerException` could be that `scanResultConfigureService.findtitleConfigure(anyString(), anyString(), anyMap())` is returning null or any intermediate method inside `findtitleConfigure` because it has not been stubbed before use.

You can create mocks for all intermediate return values and stub them before use. For example

```
FindTitleConfigure findTitleConfigure = mock(FindTitleConfigure.class);
```

Comment: According to your reminder, I thought it was because of generics. Because findtitleConfigure returned ```List <ScanResultTitleConfigurePO>```; and ```when (). ThenReturn``` returned ```List <String>```. But when I removed the generics, it still reported ```NullPointerException```.

Comment: You need to mock `findtitleConfigure` to return a list then use it.

Comment: I have tried the solution you mentioned above, but my findtitleConfigure does not have an intermediate return value.This method directly returns a List.

Comment: And in spring projects, I can only use @MockBean to mock service classes.

Comment: Oh, I think I found out what went wrong. Do you mean intermediate return refers to the database lookup method in service? After I mock the ```scanResultTitleConfigureRepository```, the unit test passed. I don’t even need to stub the ```findtitleConfigure``` method on service .