# Mockito Scala NullPointerException

Tags: scala, mockito

I am having troubles getting my first Mock working in my Chat application using Mockito, I am trying to mock a Repository that takes a user ID as a string and returns all the conversations for this user. I am having a very hard time getting rid of a `NullPointerException`

Here is my Repository trait:

```
trait UserRepository {
  val getConversations: (String) => Option[Vector[User]]
}
```

Here is my Service:

```
class UserService(userRepository: UserRepository){
  private val boolToNumber : (Boolean) => Int = (bool) => ... not useful here
  private val countToBool : (Int) => Boolean = (int) => ... not useful here

  val getParticipations: (String) => Option[Vector[User]] = (name) => {
    userRepository.getConversations(name) match {
    ... some implementation
  }
}
```

And my tests

```
  // init
  val userRepository = mock[UserRepository]

  // setup
  when(userRepository.getConversations("Smith")) thenReturn (
    Some(
      Vector(
        User("Smith", true, true, ConversationKey("Smith", "Smith and O'Connell chatroom")),
        User("Smith", false, true, ConversationKey("Smith", "Smith and O'Connell chatroom"))
      )
    )
  )
  val userService : UserService = new UserService(userRepository)
  // run
  val actual = userService.getParticipations("Smith")

  // verify
  actual mustBe Vector(User("Smith", false, true, ConversationKey("Smith", "Smith and O'Connell chatroom")))
```

What I have tried so far:

- printing after each operation in the tests, printing UserRepository returns `Mock for UserRepository, hashCode: 1319190020`, but the UserService is not printing so it is the one throwing the NullPointerException
- changing "Smith" by the matcher `any[String]`, same error, and
  `anyString` same error
- Wrapping String in a class called StringValue, same error [Mockito
  matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934179/4884034)

Comment: Try changing your val functions to def functions.

Comment: That solved it!! Thank you, do you have any idea why it would cause a NullPointerException? EDIT: Can you answer (not with a comment) so I can accept your answer?

Comment: @Daniel, can you please update your example to add how you created test class and maven or sbt dependency. I cannot get how you mock with Mockito using the following syntax: val userRepository = mock[UserRepository].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `val` functions to `def` functions.

Im not too sure exactly why this is, but mockito is a java library so im not surprised that it doesnt handle scala function values well where Def's compile to the same thing as java methods.